# I want a text book with various examples

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Which text is efficient for self-reading number theory introduction?
for the third semester of univercity

Answer (score 1):

Are you a math major?

I read and enjoyed Joe Silverman's *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory*.

It's actually intended for non-math majors;  but I read it anyhow.   I recommend it.

I have heard the book by Baker is also quite good, but haven't picked up a copy yet.

Comment: yes math major.

Comment: but I want to go to it (number theory) deeply.    @Chris Custer

Comment: It goes deeply.  It's a fun book.  Lots of examples and exercises.